# Silverlight tests run twice if try to disable TagExpressionEditor

Tags: silverlight, testing, tdd

After making the following changes in an effort to run the tests immediately:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();

        UnitTestSettings settings = UnitTestSystem.CreateDefaultSettings();
        settings.StartRunImmediately = true;
        settings.ShowTagExpressionEditor = false;

        RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage(settings);
    }
```

I find that the tests run twice. Any ideas on how I can avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue, and found that it is solved by setting the StartRunImmediately parameter to true **after** calling CreateTestPage(), and setting settings.TestService to null:

```
            settings.TestService = null;
            settings.TagExpression = e.InitParams["Tags"];
            RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage( settings );
            settings.StartRunImmediately = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

GDay guys,

look at my post here, maybe useful for you.

http://itcrank.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/dodgy-silverlight-unittest-system.html

Reason is when StartRunImmediately is set, test are called traight away in call for CreateTestPage().

Quick fix is to check for StartRunImmediately flag AFTER call for CreateTestPage(), and if flag set to true - clear test assemblies from settings before assigning test page to RootVisual of main app.

settings.TestAssemblies.Clear();

All results will be presented in UI as test already been executed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, folks may down vote or flag this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I could use some more information. I've visited your link but I'm still missing something. If I clear the testAssemblies no tests will be run